# Tomcat not shutting down properly with threaded GWT app using ExecutorService

Tags: multithreading, gwt, tomcat, memory-leaks

I'm having problems with a Google Web Toolkit Application that uses two SingleThreadExecutor threads and one FixedThreadPool. I can see from the catalina.out log that the threads aren't being shut down properly which causes the tomcat process to keep running:

```
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Oct 30, 2012 2:16:48 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/btq] appears to have started a thread named [pool-4-thread-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Oct 30, 2012 2:16:48 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/btq] appears to have started a thread named [pool-5-thread-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Oct 30, 2012 2:16:48 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/btq] appears to have started a thread named [Thread-4] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
```

I found some reference to using a ServletContextListener to handle this kind of thing, but I'm having problems getting it to work in my situation.

In one attempt I added the ServletContextListener to my GUIImpl class which is the server side implementation of the GWT code:

```
public class GUIImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements GUI, ServletContextListener
```

I guess this maybe isn't the way this is normally done, but I tried to do it this way because the class that instantiates the ExecutorService's is in another package that contains some shared code with other projects. My implementation just calls some shutdown functions on other classes, but I am getting some exceptions.

```
    @Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {

    this.context = event.getServletContext();
    context.log( "FUNCTION: GUIImpl.contextDestroyed - called" );

    // Tell the Presenter to shut down
    presenter.shutdown();
}
```

The Presenter class has an instance of a FileSystemMonitor class which is the one that instantiates the Executors. The exception in the logs is:

```
Oct 30, 2012 2:16:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: FUNCTION: GUIImpl.contextDestroyed - called
Oct 30, 2012 2:16:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class com.mdaus.btq.gui.server.GUIImpl
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at com.mdaus.btq.gui.server.GUIImpl.contextDestroyed(GUIImpl.java:1236)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4831)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5478)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Oct 30, 2012 2:16:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextDestroyed()
Oct 30, 2012 2:16:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextDestroyed()
```

Sorry if the question is a little long and confusing, but I'm a little confused right now, as I did not write the original code.

Does anyone have ideas as to how I can shut down these threads?